# Internal Memcheck Error: Memcheck failed initialization as profiler is attached

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have always used `cuda-memcheck` under Windows 7.

Unfortunately, on my laptop I'm now getting the following error message:

```
========= Internal Memcheck Error: Memcheck failed initialization as profiler is attached. Try unsetting CUDA_PROFILE or disabling the profiler.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:C:\windows\system32\nvcuda.dll (cuD3D11CtxCreate + 0x103dbd) [0x11fe1d]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\cudart32_55.dll (_cudaRegisterDeviceFunction + 0x5eb2) [0xdaf2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\cudart32_55.dll (_cudaRegisterDeviceFunction + 0x600d) [0xdc4d]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\cudart32_55.dll (_cudaRegisterDeviceFunction + 0x6576) [0xe1b6]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\cudart32_55.dll (_cudaRegisterDeviceFunction + 0x3609) [0xb249]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\cudart32_55.dll [0x3137]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\cudart32_55.dll (cudaMalloc + 0xb5) [0x152d5]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\StackOverflow.exe (main + 0x59) [0x2289]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\StackOverflow.exe (__tmainCRTStartup + 0x1bf) [0xa3ef]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Users\user\Documents\Project\StackOverflow\Debug\StackOverflow.exe (mainCRTStartup + 0xf) [0xa21f]
=========     Host Frame:C:\windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll (BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12) [0x1336a]
=========     Host Frame:C:\windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll (RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63) [0x39f72]
=========     Host Frame:C:\windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll (RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36) [0x39f45]
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

I have checked about the existence of a `CUDA_PROFILE` environmental variable, but it is not defined neither as a system nor as a user variable. I have anyway set

```
Set @CUDA_PROFILE = 0
```

but with no effect. I'm using CUDA 5.5.

I have tried using `cuda-memcheck` also on other two systems, a `4`-GPU, NVIDIA K20c system and a system having a single Tesla C2050 card. On the former I have the same problem, on the latter `cuda-memcheck` works fine.

The fact that the error says *the profile is attached* makes me think that the problem could be due to a Visual Studio *attachments to process* that I have previously done on the two machines `cuda-memcheck` is not working on. The machine `cuda-memcheck` is working on has been freshly installed, instead. However, I have checked that `NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER` environmental variable used for such a kind of attachments is set to `0`. Also. I couldn't spot any appearent process that could still be attached to the debugger.

*Could anyone suggest any hint to solve the problem?*

Comment: 1. Could you check that the attach functionality in the Nsight Monitor is disabled? You can do this by right clicking on the Nsight Monitor tray icon, hit Properties and go the CUDA section and disable "Use this Monitor for CUDA attach". 2. Could you also check if the environment variables CUDA_INJECTION32_PATH and CUDA_INJECTION64_PATH exist and if so, delete them and retry ?

Comment: @Vyas Thank you very much for your suggestions. I forgot to mention that I had already done test #1 at the time of writing the post, but without success. Also and concerning test #2, I deleted the environmental variables `CUDA_INJECTION32_PATH` and `CUDA_INJECTION64_PATH`, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Did you previously use the command line profiler(nvprof) in daemon mode ? Could you make sure that task manager does not show any processes named `nvprof` running in the background ? Could you also try the following : From a command line, run `nvprof --profile-all-processes`, then hit `ctrl+c` to terminate nvprof. At that point, retry running the app with cuda-memcheck.

Comment: @Vyas I have solved the problem. I had to set the `COMPUTE_PROFILE` environmental variable to `0`. Actually, running `nvprof --profile-all-processes` moved me to the right direction since it returned an error message different from `cuda-memcheck`. More in detail, while cuda-memcheck was complaining about `CUDA_PROFILE`, `nvprof` was complaining about `COMPUTE_PROFILE` which I had to set to `0` to launch `nvprof`. This solved also the `cuda-memcheck` problem.

Comment: @Vyas As a double check, I have set `CUDA_PROFILE` to `1` and `cuda-memcheck` keeps working. So, `COMPUTE_PROFILE` should be set to `0` and `cuda-memcheck` works regardless to the value of `CUDA_PROFILE`.

Comment: could somebody write an answer?  I will upvote it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have written an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When experiencing the problem with `cuda-memcheck`, my system environmental variable `COMPUTE_PROFILE` was set to `1`. I had just to set it to `0` to have `cuda-memcheck` work correctly. Incidentally, I have to thank @Vjas for suggesting checking `nvprof --profile-all-processes`which complained about the setting of `CUDA_PROFILE`. I have solved the problem on my laptop and on the Kepler system by setting `COMPUTE_PROFILE=0`.

I have today no access to the Tesla system, on which `cuda-memcheck` was properly working, to check about the setting of `COMPUTE_PROFILE`. I will update this answer as soon as I have such an information.

**EDIT**

I have checked that the environmental variable `COMPUTE_PROFILE` was not defined on the system where `cuda-memcheck` was originally working.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar with CUDA 6.5 and 7.0. The error message was slightly more general (which may be due to the different version - I'm not sure about that). It said

> Internal Memcheck Error: Memcheck failed initialization as some other tools is currently attached. Please make sure that nvprof and Nsight Visual Studio Edition are not being run simultaneously

(Of course, there *was* no other tool running at this time).

Setting the `COMPUTE_PROFILE` environment variable to `0` did not help. (Actually, it was not set at all for me in the first place).

Finally, I figured out that the odd behavior was caused by other environment variables: The toolkit/profiler obviously sets two additional environment variables during the installation:

```
CUDA_INJECTION32_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Visual Studio Edition 4.1\Monitor\Common\Injection32\Nvda.Cuda.Injection.dll
CUDA_INJECTION64_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Visual Studio Edition 4.1\Monitor\Common\Injection64\Nvda.Cuda.Injection.dll
```

I'm not sure what they are doing (most likely, they establish some "hook" that is required for profiling). In any case: Removing these environment variables (or setting them to be empty by executing

```
set CUDA_INJECTION32_PATH=
set CUDA_INJECTION64_PATH=
```

at the command prompt where `cuda-memcheck` should be launched) caused `cuda-memcheck` to work properly again.

**UPDATE**

I was getting the same error on my Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7 machines with Geforce GTX 780 GPUs. Though the procedure explained above worked for me, I found out that CUDA_INJECTION32_PATH and CUDA_INJECTION64_PATH environment variables are added and set by Nsight Monitor when its setting "CUDA->Use this monitor for CUDA attach" is to true by the user.

In order to fix the initialization problem of cuda-memcheck, I simply turned off the setting "CUDA->Use this monitor for CUDA attach" in Nsight monitor. This  deleted the CUDA_INJECTION32_PATH and CUDA_INJECTION64_PATH  environment variables. Thereafter I opened a new session of command prompt to reload new environment variables and tested that cuda-memcheck worked properly.

Comment: Thanks @nurabha for the update. When I ran into this, I explicitly closed the NSight monitor, and even rebootet the whole system, but the environment variables had still been there. I did not consider that they might be UN-set by UN-setting some checkbox. (I have not yet tried it, but assuming that it really works, this may be an easier way to solve this issue)

Comment: (BTW: I just noticed that the hint that this may be related to the `CUDA_INJECTIONxx_PATH` variables was already given by @Vyas in his first comment to the question, and he also mentioned the possible solution from the "update". Not sure why this did not work for the original asker, but hopefully, anybody who runs into this issue will now be able to solve it either way)

Comment: Thanks. `set CUDA_INJECTION64_PATH=` suffices for x64 processes.

Answer (score 2):

The error I ran into was just `Internal Memcheck Error: Initialization failed` when trying to use the `cuFFT` library. As per the [nvidia forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-memcheck-failed-on-cufft-library/115286/8) the solution is to set the `CUDA_MEMCHECK_PATCH_MODULE` environment variable.

```sh
export CUDA_MEMCHECK_PATCH_MODULE=1
```

Comment: This changed behavior, but did not entirely eliminate the issue in my case. However, it did make it clear that cufft was part of the issue. It also led me to discover that `cuda-memcheck` is being replaced by a new tool called `compute-sanitizer`. The release notes indicate the new tool only works for newer devices.